# Will removing extra chainring mess with chain alignment?

Tags: cassette, chainring, drivetrain, folding-bicycle, alignment

I have a folding bike with 1x6 speed. I plan on making it a 1x9. I saw this crank set and cassette, 3x9 speed, for a fairly cheap amount and was thinking of getting them and installing on my bike. If I were to remove the 2 other chainrings from the crank set, would that mess with the alignment of my chain? Is there any harm in doing this?

Comment: Before you get ahead of yourself, can your folder even take a 9 speed cassette? And why do you want to replace the crank?

Comment: @Batman I believe so. I measured the rear spacing and it's at 135mm. As for the crank, just to match everything else because I already replaced the brakes and derailleur.

Comment: @dork it is not just the rear spacing, it is the space for the cassette itself.

Comment: Typically, 6 speeds are freewheels, 9 speeds are cassettes (though we are seeing more 9 speed freewheels presumably for E-bikes). So you're likely looking at a new wheel too.

Comment: Ah yes, they do include new hubs as well.